# SSIS/SSRS -- I am getting this error, when I am creating a new project for SSIS in VS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2017, ssis-2017

New to Reporting Services, I am getting this error when creating a new project

[image: The error image attached]

Comment: I'd check event viewer and/or uninstall/reinstall the SSDT bits

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the reply. I uninstalled SSDT and issue solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my train of thought from comments

The Class not registered error smelled like something was wrong in the registry but *what* was missing was going to impossible to troubleshoot. Going through the uninstall/reinstall process appears to have gotten all the correct classes registered and the tool is now working.